# Why is "ie.waitforcomplete 10000" not working?

Tags: g1ant

According to the syntax of `ie.waitforcomplete` command, it takes input in terms of milliseconds but while I was running this code, it does for 10 seconds as it should.

```
ie.open google.com nowait true
window ✱internet✱
ie.seturl g1ant.com 
ie.waitforcomplete 1000
ie.seturl duckduckgo.com
```

Answer (score 2):

As manual suggests, [ie.waiforcomplete](https://manual.g1ant.com/G1ANT.Addons/G1ANT.Addon.IExplorer/Commands/IEWaitForCompleteCommand.md) "suspends script execution until a webpage is loaded". The first argument is `timeout` which "specifies time in milliseconds for G1ANT.Robot to wait for the command to be executed". It simply means that when you have:

```
ie.waitforcomplete 1000
```

It will wait for maximum time of 1000 milliseconds (1 second) for a webpage to load, if it fails, an exception will occurr.

And the following code means that it will wait for maximum time of 10 seconds.

```
ie.waitforcomplete 10000
```

Comment: I had even tried ie.waitforcomplete 50000 but it doesn't more than 1 second.

Comment: As I said, if the webpage is loaded faster than your 50000 milliseconds, the script will continue. It will go to the next command. If you want to suspend the script execution, simply use the `delay` command.